# is there an aws cloudformation template for creating a default vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

After deleting the default vpc, is there a cloudformation template that can recreate it?

Is there a particular flag that signifies that it is a default vpc?

when creating via cli `aws ec2 create-default-vpc` the returned json contains a `"IsDefault": true,"InstanceTenancy": "default"` , can this be used in a CF template to flag the creation as well, assuming the `"CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/16",` is set as well?

Comment: You have to use custom resource to create default vpc using CFN.

Comment: i do currently use multiple custom resource snippets in the template, but did not see a flag for `IsDefault`. can you point to a document or example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to create a default VPC through a pure CloudFormation template.

To create a default VPC, you need to invoke the [CreateDefaultVpc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDefaultVpc.html) API. You can do this in CloudFormation with a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that allows you to run custom provisioning logic in a Lambda function.

Note: you cannot have multiple default VPCs per account/region. You can determine if you have a default VPC by calling the [DescribeAccountAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAccountAttributes.html) API. It will provide the following attribute in the response:

- default-vpc: The ID of the default VPC for your account, or none.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

To create a default VPC using the console
Open the Amazon VPC console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/.

- In the navigation pane, choose Your VPCs.
- Choose Actions, Create Default VPC.
- Choose Create. Close the confirmation screen.

Here is the doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html

And here is a template for a VPC in cloudformation if you need: https://github.com/caiocsgomes/template-vpc-cloudformation

Comment: does this CF template create a default VPC or just a standard non default VPC? as per @jarmod there does not seem to be a flag for default vpc in CF

Comment: non default, to create a default VPC the process is the one specified before, or in the docs